# How to integrate schema changes to existing database with NHibernate?

Tags: database, nhibernate

these are the rules for the game:

0) You have to use NHibernate;

1) You have a working database with data which must stay "alive" after the update;

2) If you have 3 versions of the database schema (1.0, 2.0 and 3.0) you should be able to update low->high version. (high->low is optional);

I know about the methods schema.Create()/Update() but I am not sure what is the best configuration for them. Also I want to know how you actually handle such situations.

Hala...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called "migration". There is no migration tool build in NHiberante. You have to use an external tools like tarentino, red get sql compare, etc.

Comment: Tarantino sounds good. Any tips that are beyond the tarantino's wiki are welcome

Comment: You can use Tarantino combined with a script that generates migrations from the current NHibernate sessionfactory and the previous migrations. Click a .bat file to create a new migration. You can also integrate Tarantino with your build script, or use sql-command in the build scipt when the migrations are very simple. I don't use Tarantino in an advanced way, so I cannot give you a tip beyond the wiki. The redgate sql tools can be worth the money when you have to release very frequently.